# Authentication Failure with GITHUB Token Authentication

Tags: github

I'm having issues trying to push to my remote repository, I have generated my PAT and when prompted for username: & the password:. I then insert the PAT into my password instead of my password and I am still getting an authentication error: -

> remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.
> remote: Please see https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently recommended modes of authentication.
> fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/stephenwelch1927/Practice.git/'

I am wondering am I missing a step or something?

I generated the access token as per GitHub docs, copied it into the password prompt and it still gave me an authentication error.

Comment: Did you generate a new style scoped PAT or a legacy PAT? If you use the scoped ones and the token doesn't have the right permissions, this is the error you seem to get.

Comment: I recommend installing the Git Credential Manager Core and have its UI handle the token generation on your behalf.

Comment: https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager

Comment: What scopes did you give the PAT when you crated it?

Comment: I gave my PAT full access to everything including full access to repos pull/push etc. I iwlll try the credentialManager. Thank you for your help everyone.

Comment: I am just wondering do I need to enable PAT to work or should they work automatically?